# Use local function variable inside loop

Tags: python, loops, variables

```
def loop():
    d = 0
    for x in range(12):
        d+=1 #this 'd' is not the same as the one above.
    print(d)
```

In the code above, wouldn't the local variable of the function still be 0? How can I change this to use the function variable instead of the internal variable of the loop?

Comment: Are your indentation what you want it to be because right now `d` will become `12`

Comment: "wouldn't the local variable of the function still be 0?" - which local variable? I see two, neither of which would be 0 at the end of the loop.

Comment: @MooingRawr the loop would affect the value of D in the function.

Comment: okie.... so what is the problem? I don't see an issue with the code you posted. If there's other code maybe post it and explain it better?

Comment: "wouldn't the local variable of the function still be 0?" Yeah if only there was a way to try this before asking inane questions.

Comment: What do you mean by 'function variable'?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you've gotten confused between scope outside of a function and inside of it.

```
d = 1
def a():
    d = 0 # this is a different d from line 1
    for x in range(12):
        d += 1 # this is the same d as line 3
    print(d) # same d as line 3
print(d) # same d as line 1
```

You probably read about locally scoped variables but have gotten confused. Indenting your line does not create a "new local scope". The only time that happens is within functions.

Answer (score 1):

That's not how scope works in Python.  The `d` in the function is accessible by the loop within the function.  They are the same `d`.

```
def loop():
    d = 0
    for x in range(12):
        d+=1 #this 'd' IS the same as the one above.
    print(d)

loop()
```

Running the code proves that it is the same `d`.

**output:**

> 12

...Your code does what you want.  Please run your code and see the output before asking.

Answer (score 1):

In a general way Python does not change the scope of variables inside loop (`for`, `while`) or `if` constructs:

you have a single `d` variable in your function, regardless of using it inside the loop or not.

There are exceptions, though - one of which is that you can use loops inside list comprehensions or generator expressions - the variables used in these loops are local to the expression - althought, being expressions, they don't allow for general assignment of variables:

```
def a():
   d = 0
   any(print(d) for d in range(12))
   print("main d:", d)
```

(This example uses Python 3 print function).

The other exception is the variable to which an exception is assignet in a
`try`...`except` block. That variable is local to the except block, and ceases existing out of it- but instead of having a  nested scope, Python does erase the variable from the current scope:

```
In [34]: def b():
    ...:   a = 1
    ...:   try:
    ...:     1 / 0
    ...:   except ZeroDivisionError as a:
    ...:     print(a)
    ...:   print(a)
    ...:    

In [35]: b()
division by zero
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
UnboundLocalError                         Traceback (most recent call last)
...
----> 7   print(a)
      8
```