# python inner functions treat mutable vs immutable variables differently

Tags: python

I am trying to understand why does the inner function has access to the outer list (arr) but not the outer boolean variable (found).

```
def outer():
    arr = [1, 2, 3]
    found = False
    print("outer func ids: ", id(arr), id(found))
    def inner(num):
        arr.append(4)
        found = True
        print("inner func ids:", id(arr), id(found))
    inner(3)
    print("outer func ids: ", id(arr), id(found))
    return found
outer()
```

Output:

```
('outer func ids: ', 4536180248, 140736008926072)
('inner func ids:', 4536180248, 140736008926048)
('outer func ids: ', 4536180248, 140736008926072)
```

Can someone please clarify. Why does the list have the same id even though we are doing append operation in the inner function ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Use local function variable inside loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41367656/use-local-function-variable-inside-loop)

Comment: Because you explicitly reassign the variable. Please read https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html This has nothing to do with mutable/immutable. If you did `arr = ['foo','bar']` you'd see the same result. Note, **variables** are neither mutable nor immutable, the *objects the refer to* can be. But variables can be reassigned to any sort of object. Python does not have typed variables

Comment: And note, if you *didn't* reassign `found` in `inner`, and simply did `print(id(found))` you'd see the same object (although in this case, it's sort of moot since `True` and `False` are singletons).

Comment: what I am not getting clarity is, why did the array have the same id in-spite of having an append operation ?

Answer (score 1):

Because redefining `found` in `inner` makes it local. Nothing to do with mutable or not.

Answer (score 0):

It's because Python uses static scope/is statically scoped. At implementation level Python has what is called a Symbol Table which has entries for things you define in code like variables and functions.

Each of those things are represented by a lexeme and have attributes like "value" and "scope".

For example for the first found, you have:

```
LEXEME |  VALUE | SCOPE

found  |  False |  outer
```

When you defined a second found, an entry was generated for that found with a scope "inner". So at the moment of execution of  `print("inner func ids:", id(arr), id(found))` Python searched the Symbol Table for an entry of "found" and used the most recent one (the one with the inner scope). Like this:

```
LEXEME |  VALUE | SCOPE

found  |  False |  outer
found  |  True  |  inner
```

The array is just unique, so when searching for that `arr` you again get the last entry for that lexeme or symbol and get the value of the unique outer array.

It's not about mutable or immutable but rather about scope.

Answer (score 0):

From python [Faq](https://docs.python.org/3/faq/programming.html#id9)

Python, variables that are only referenced inside a function are implicitly global. If a variable is assigned a value anywhere within the function’s body, it’s assumed to be a local unless explicitly declared as global.

Though a bit surprising at first, a moment’s consideration explains this. On one hand, requiring global for assigned variables provides a bar against unintended side-effects. On the other hand, if global was required for all global references, you’d be using global all the time. You’d have to declare as global every reference to a built-in function or to a component of an imported module. This clutter would defeat the usefulness of the global declaration for identifying side-effects.

Try **not** to assign value to `found` and see its id.

Let's see some examples:

```
a = [1, 2, 3]
b = True
c = 123
d = "Hello"

def print_global1():
  print("print_global1: a=", a, id(a))
  print("print_global1: b=", b, id(b))
  print("print_global1: c=", c, id(c))
  print("print_global1: d=", d, id(d))

def print_global2():
  global a, b, c, d
  print("print_global2: a=", a, id(a))
  print("print_global2: b=", b, id(b))
  print("print_global2: c=", c, id(c))
  print("print_global2: d=", d, id(d))

def print_global3():
  global a, b, c, d
  a.append(4)
  b = False
  c += 1
  d = d.upper()
  print("print_global3: a=", a, id(a))
  print("print_global3: b=", b, id(b))
  print("print_global3: c=", c, id(c))
  print("print_global3: d=", d, id(d))

print("a=", a, id(a))
print("b=", b, id(b))
print("c=", c, id(c))
print("c=", d, id(c))
print("")
print_global1()
print("")
print_global2()
print("")
print_global3()
```

The outputs are:

```
a= [1, 2, 3] 3206482320648
b= True 1625616544
c= 123 1626110848
c= Hello 1626110848

print_global1: a= [1, 2, 3] 3206482320648
print_global1: b= True 1625616544
print_global1: c= 123 1626110848
print_global1: d= Hello 3206481522616

print_global2: a= [1, 2, 3] 3206482320648
print_global2: b= True 1625616544
print_global2: c= 123 1626110848
print_global2: d= Hello 3206481522616

print_global3: a= [1, 2, 3, 4] 3206482320648
print_global3: b= False 1625616576
print_global3: c= 124 1626110880
print_global3: d= HELLO 3206482331664
```